# Github Removing unwanted files

Tags: git, github

I created a repo on github with some photos included in the original repo, I have redesigned my project and removed the unwanted photos locally, then pushed my changes up to github. The old photos still remain in the github repo...How do I remove them? Did I miss a step somewhere? Im a total newbie and this is very challenging for me. Thank You!

Comment: I'm going to make the safe assumption that you synced your changes, right?

Comment: I am a total newbie and really struggling with Git and Github. What does "syncing changes" mean and what command would I have used and where? Im sorry to be so basic, but I am losing sleep trying to learn this! Thanks for replying!

Comment: Alright. Do you have the GitHub Desktop Client installed?

Comment: yes but Im in school and we are not learning how to use it. We are using the command line.

Comment: Oh, that poses a different problem. Good to hear you're learning, but I think the command line is a bit too much to learn from the get-go. So, there are three ways to do this, which I will outline in a formal answer.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, first off, it looks like your problem stems from the discrepancy from the *local* repository and the *remote* repository. The local is the stuff on your computer, which you're editing - but the remote is the one on GitHub's servers. If you change things on local, it does not change things in remote unless you run a few other commands. If you're using Git command-line, there are three things you should learn for this.

**A: git push**
`git push` is Git's command to send files to the remote server. Maneuver to the proper repository with `cd`, pick your branch with `git checkout <name>`, and then call `git push`, which will send those changes up to the website and make them keep.

**B: git pull**
`git pull` is the natural opposite of `push`: if the latter sends things up to the server, `pull` brings them down, and applies the remote changes to the local repository. Just like `push`, maneuver to the repository and branch, and `git pull`. (Side note: `git fetch` is a similar command, except that it *does not overwrite local changes*, instead hiding the changes in the secret `.git` folder, to be merged later -- in fact, `pull` uses `fetch` and `merge` as a two-step process in one command. But don't worry too much about that.)

**C: (Optional) git sync**
As mentioned above, `pull` is actually just a shortcut for `git fetch` and then `git merge FETCH_HEAD`. And, in a similar manner, `git sync` is a handy command which is aliased to `!git pull && git push` -- in other words, it both pulls *and* pushes changes, all at once. I personally prefer to sync, always, over anything else, though there may be times when you'll prefer to use just one or the other.

That should be the simplest fix to your problem, but if that doesn't cure it, look at the other answers. Maybe the problem isn't as complex as I imagined. In any case, once you can, get a moment to glance at the GitHub Desktop Client, which handles most of this stuff for you, and more, and will satisfy most things you want to do with git through a much easier interface.

PS: A tip for the future, check out the commands that come up when you enter `git help`. And before you use anything, use `git help <command name>`, such as `git help commit`.

Comment: Thank You so much for your detailed answer! I guess I just simply dont understand all the processes and therefore I am totally lost! when you "pull" from remote, where does it go? does it overwrite anything locally? What is the purpose of pulling if my local copy has all my changes? I would be pulling down the old photos I just deleted. Im so sorry, but I am just lost!

Comment: Pulling from the remote will sync up the commits from the remote, which will overwrite your current files if you're still on a previous commit state, but will NOT if you are past it. Say you have three remote commits A-B-C, but your local commits are only at A-B. When you pull, your files will be updated to C. However, if you have A-B-C-D, pulling will change nothing, because you are already past C. If you have made modifications at B, though, that results in merging issues... which you shouldn't have to worry about, if you're only working from one computer.

Comment: You can mostly disregard pulling for your problem, but if you plan to use git for future work, I figured it would be useful to learn now rather than later.

Comment: Better, simpler analogy - just pretend you have two computers connected. Computer A is local, B is remote. If you make a change on A, B doesn't know about it until you *push* from A to B. Once you've pushed, if another person (C) needs to see your changes, they need to pull the change off of B, and now C is up to date.

Comment: Thanks so much for trying to help me. I appreciate it so much. I guess I understand the analogy, just dont understand why B kept my old photos. Im thinking the easiest way to get rid of them now is to delete that remote repo and start over! (although in the real world I wouldnt do that, so trying to figure out how I would do it once on the job)

Comment: The reason it still has your old files is because you haven't changed anything on "Computer B". Things on the remote don't change until you push, because the remote is not your own computer. It needs to be told what has been changed. If you and three others are told to go to point A, but one other person realizes it would be better to go to point B, they need to tell you before you know that the location has changed -- you don't know as soon as they change it. Makes sense?

Comment: I did push, and they are still there, that was my whole problem.

Comment: Oh. Huh. How strange... In that case I'm not sure what the problem is. Sorry.

Comment: By any chance, is the repo public? I can look at it and I might be able to come in with a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use:

git rm nameofpic.jpg

git commit -m "Removing file from git repo"

Comment: I did that locally, but then when I push it up to github, the old files are still there from before.

Answer (score 0):

### Use git-filter-branch or BFG

You need to [purge the files](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/#purging-a-file-from-your-repositorys-history) from your local and GitHub repositories. GitHub provides some step-by-step instructions using git-filter-branch, but the easiest way is by [using BFG](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/#using-the-bfg). For example:

```
bfg --delete-files \*.jpg
```

You can learn more about the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), including features and options, from the project's web site.

Note that once you have purged the files from your repository, you will need to force-push your modified history to GitHub, and others will likely need to re-clone the new repository. The DAG of a filtered repository often makes it difficult (although not always impossible) for downstream clones to sync with the new history graph without re-cloning. However, YMMV.

Comment: Thanks but that is way too advanced for me. I am so confused with this. I am tempted to delete the github repo and start over!